# pretty urls from database

Tags: php, database, slug

I am trying get pretty urls on my site..right now they look like this:

```
www.site.com/tag.php?id=1
```

I want to change that to

```
www.site.com/tag/1/slug
```

my database table has ID,Title,Info,Slug

I read online about slugs,but being new to php found no luck,can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

First create an `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
# Turn on rewrite engine and redirect broken requests to index
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* router.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Then, set the following code for `router.php`:

```
<?php

$segments=explode('/',trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/'),3);

switch($segments[0]){
    case 'tag': // tag/[id]/[slug]
        $_REQUEST['id']=(int)$segments[1];
        $_GET['id']=(int)$segments[1];
        $slug=$segments[2];
        require_once('tag.php');
        break;
}

?>
```

**Further Clarification**

*Htaccess*

The concept behind the htaccess is very simple. Instead of listening for URL patterns (as old htaccess software did), we simply reroute all traffic that would otherwise result in a 404 to `router.php`, which in turn takes care of doing what is required. There are 3 rewrite entries; for (sym)links, files and directories (`/aaa` is seen as a file while `/aaa/bbb` is seen as a folder)

*Router*

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` looks like `"/tag/1/slug"`. We first trim it against redundant  slashes and then explode it in 3 items (so we don't affect slug, which might contain other slashes), `print_r`ing the `$segments` (for tags/45/Hello/World) would look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tag
    [1] => 45
    [2] => Hello/World
)
```

Finally, since I see you want to redirect to `tags.php?id=1`, what you need to do is to set `$_REQUEST['id']` and `$_GET['id']` manually and load `tags.php`.

Comment: Thanks @christian-sciberras,I tried the .htaccess and router.php.and now when i go to tag/1/slug it just takes me to router.php.what am i doing wrong??

Comment: Make sure you have apache mod_rewrite installed and enabled.

Comment: @christian-sciberras how do you add $_REQUEST['id'] and $_GET['id'] manually?...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this guide:

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

// not my blog...

or this which seems better:

http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html

EDIT:

this is for apache, as I assumed this was what you were using